# Cannot find table 0 in dataset using stored procedures

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am not getting filled dataset after executing a stored procedure.

```
protected void btnsub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    ArrayList arInsert = ReturnParameter_insert();
    DataSet dsInsertProfile = objadmin.GetGridData(arInsert, objconstant.sSP_INSERT_PROFILE);

    if(int.Parse(dsInsertProfile.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString())== 0)
    {
         lblThank.Text = "Your profile have been successfully saved.";
    }
    else
    {
        lblThank.Text = "Your profile is not saved, please try again later.";
    }
}

public ArrayList ReturnParameter_insert()
{
    ArrayList arProfile = new ArrayList();
    Object[] c_first_name = new object[3] { "@strFname", "Varchar", (txtfname.Text != "") ? txtfname.Text : "" };
    arProfile.Add(c_first_name);
    return arProfile;
}

public DataSet GetGridData(ArrayList dbArray, string sSpName)
{
        DataSet dsDataSet = new DataSet();
        dsDataSet = datamanager.GetGridData(dbArray, sSpName);
        return dsDataSet;
}

public static SqlDbType GetSqlDataType(string sDataType)
{
    return (sDataType == "Integer") ? SqlDbType.Int : (sDataType == "Varchar") ? SqlDbType.VarChar : (sDataType == "Date") ? SqlDbType.Date : SqlDbType.BigInt;
}

public static DataSet GetGridData(ArrayList dbArray, string sSpName)
{
        DataSet dsDataSet = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection cn = createConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = sSpName;

        object objPrMtrName;
        object objSqlType;
        object objPrMtrVal;
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < dbArray.Count; i++)
        {
            objPrMtrName = ((object[])(dbArray[i]))[0];
            objSqlType = ((object[])(dbArray[i]))[1];
            objPrMtrVal = ((object[])(dbArray[i]))[2];
            cmd.Parameters.Add(objPrMtrName.ToString(), GetSqlDataType(objSqlType.ToString())).Value = objPrMtrVal;
        }

        cmd.Connection = cn;

        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adp.Fill(dsDataSet);
            return dsDataSet;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
            cn.Dispose();
        }
}
```

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE Procedure spInsert_profile
    (@strFname  varchar(200))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO gdt_Users([c_first_name], [d_modified_dttm], [d_created_dttm])
    VALUES(@strFname, GETDATE(), GETDATE())
END
```

Here I am using 3 tier, the same methods are working successfully for other pages but not for this particular code. The dataset in GETGRIDDATA method is filling null value. I am not able to find. Please help me....

Comment: to start with try executing your stored procedure on SQL Server Management studio and check if it works.

Comment: @Yasser my store procedure is working fine i did some changes.

Comment: so, is your problem resolved ? if yes, in that case post that answer here.

Answer (score 1):

you performing insert operation in your procedure than how is going to return to data `Insert into statement` does insert operation not retrieve operation.

...To retrieve data you need to call procedure with `select *` statement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no select statement in your stored proc. adapter.fill() should recieve some sort of table from the stored proc's output.

Comment: Thank u all for replying which helped me a lot..ya sure , i have problem in my store procedure... I added select statement to storeprocedure

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see here you are executing a stored procedure that only performs an INSERT command, The reason you are getting a NULL value back is because a non query command such as UPDATE or INSERT will generally return only the number of rows affected e.g. 1 and not the data of the table you inserted to.

You would need to perform a SELECT command after the insert to  get any data back.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `Insert Into` in your stored procedure.

Access based on `Tables`  property:

```
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
adp.Fill(dsDataSet);
var table1 = dsDataSet.Tables[0];
var table2 = dsDataSet.Tables[1];
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.dataset.tables.aspx

Comment: Thank u all for replying which helped me a lot..:)

Comment: Hi,  the problem has been solved in store procedure for a particular page .then again i am using the same procedure for other aspx page, it is giving error at this stage.                                                                  public ArrayList ReturnParameter_insert()
    {
    ArrayList arProfile = new ArrayList();
    Object[] c_first_name = new object[3] { "@strFname","Varchar", (txtfname.Text != "") ? txtfname.Text : "" };
    arProfile.Add(c_first_name);
    return arProfile;
}

Comment: ya sure , i have problem in my store procedure... I changed it to   **bold**CREATE Procedure spInsert_profile
(
@strFname  varchar(200)

)
AS
BEGIN                                                             
Insert into gdt_Users([c_first_name] ,[d_modified_dttm],[d_created_dttm])values(@strFname,GETDATE(),GETDATE())
END

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your stored procedure... you have to add select statement to the stored procedure for your return result in **DataSet**